# Problem with white edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I want to composite a cube over a background while still keeping the alpha channel for the cube. I want the composited image to be a cube over an image. The alpha channel should be only the cube. I would like to use the alpha channel as a mask for further compositing. The problem is that with my current node setup there is a border around the cube.

**[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27231)**

[image]